# Spawned player can't communicate with server

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity-networking

I am using a local WAMP server to connect everything. I get no errors when I initiate the server and then connect the client. Everything seems to run great until the player spawns and it tells me "SpawnObject for SkeletonPlayer(Clone) (UnityEngine.GameObject), NetworkServer is not active. Cannot spawn objects without an active server." Any ideas as to what is going on?

```
void OnGUI()
{
if (isAtStartup)
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(2, 10, 150, 100), "Press S for server");
        GUI.Label(new Rect(2, 50, 150, 100), "Press R for registered servers");
        GUI.Label(new Rect(2, 90, 150, 100), "Press C for client");
    }
}

public void SetupServer()
{
    //connecting to my server
    NetworkServer.Listen(4444);
    isAtStartup = false;
    Debug.Log("Server Connected");
}

 public void SetupClient()
{
    ClientScene.RegisterPrefab(playerPrefab);

    myClient = new NetworkClient();

    myClient.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnConnected);
    myClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 4444);      

    isAtStartup = false;      
}

// Create a local client and connect to the local server
public void SetupLocalClient()
{
    myClient = ClientScene.ConnectLocalServer();
    myClient.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnConnected);
    isAtStartup = false;
}

// client function
public void OnConnected(NetworkMessage netMsg)
{
    Debug.Log("Connected to server");
            GameObject player = (GameObject)Instantiate(playerPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            NetworkServer.Spawn(player);
    }
}
```

Comment: any luck, I am having the same issue.

Comment: same here , and my problem is that my game only has gui as the playerprefab , maybe thats why ?

Comment: You shuld use the [commad]